# django-sphinx: SphinxClient instance has no attribute 'SetFieldWeights'

Tags: python, full-text-search, django-sphinx

In my models, when I refer to SphinxSearch with defaults like:

```
from djangosphinx.models import SphinxSearch

class Blog(models.Model):
    ...
    search = SphinxSearh()
```

the fulltext search works fine. But when I give `weights` attribute as documented:

```
search = SphinxSearch(
    weights={'title': 10, 'body': 5, 'tags': 10}
)
```

searches raise: `SphinxClient instance has no attribute 'SetFieldWeights'`

I must be missing something obvious as I seem to be the only one with this problem after Googling. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is coming due to version of sphinxapi, put

> SPHINX_API_VERSION = 0x116

in your settings.py file. problem will get resolve.

Default version getting picked up is 0x107, which doesn't have implemented 'SetFieldWeights' function.